# How can inject interactor from presenter with Koin

Tags: android, kotlin, koin

I'm new at Koin. I have set all the stuff and is working. But I'm getting some problems when I'm trying to inject interactor and presenter at the same time. That not sure it is possible.

This is my Module

```
val applicationModule = module(override = true) {
    factory{VoucherImpl(get())}
    factory<VoucherContract.Presenter> { (view: VoucherContract.View) -> VoucherPresenter(view, get()) }


}
```

This is my Activity where inject the presenter

```
 private val presenter: VoucherContract.Presenter by inject { parametersOf(this)}
```

This is my Presenter

```
class VoucherPresenter (private var view: VoucherContract.View?, private var mCodeRechargeInteract : VoucherImpl) : VoucherContract.Presenter, VoucherContract.Callback, KoinComponent {

    override fun create() {
        view?.initView()
        view?.showProgress()
        mCodeRechargeInteract.run()
    }
.
.
.
```

Interactor class

```
class VoucherImpl(private var mCallback: VoucherContract.Callback?) : AbstractInteractor() {
.
.
.
```

contract

```
interface VoucherContract {


    interface Presenter {
        fun create()
        fun destroy()
        fun checkIfShoppingCartHaveItems()
        fun addVoucherToShoppingCart(voucherProduct: Product)
        fun onItemClick(product: Product)
    }

    interface Callback {
        fun onResponseVouchers(vouchers: List<Product>?)
        fun onError()
    }

}
```

With this code I get

```
No definition found for 'xxx.voucher.VoucherContract$Callback' has been found. Check your module definitions.
```

Then, I try to put it in the module and I can't do it because I get: a Type mismatch. Required `VoucherContract.Callback` Found `VoucherImpl`

```
factory<VoucherContract.Callback> { (callBack: VoucherContract.Callback) -> VoucherImpl(callBack) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a circular dependency that's why this doesn't work.

`VoucherImpl(VoucherContract.Callback)` and `VoucherPresenter(View, VoucherImpl):VoucherContract.Callback`

There are multiple ways out of this predicament.
I would recommend the following changes:
The `VoucherImpl` should not have the constructor parameter `VoucherContract.Callback`. This callback should be the parameter of a method something like this:

```
class VoucherImpl : AbstractInteractor(){
  fun listen(VoucherContract.Callback){...}
}
```

This way the dependency becomes one way and you can inject them.

Comment: Doing in this way, I need to init the parameter with laeinit to can use it in whole class. Then, how can I set callback to null to destroy the callback, because a laeinit can't be set to null:  private lateinit var mCallback: VoucherContract.Callback // fun listen(callback: VoucherContract.Callback){this.mCallback = callback} //override fun removeCallbacks() {
        mCallback = null 
    } Or will be remove when the activity that handle this class will be destroy?

Comment: Maybe have a read here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide 
This will help you to have a more reactive architecture with clean dependencies.